# Can't snap to the another feature while translating/move Interaction in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, angular

When I try to snap one feature to another feature while translating the feature it was not snapping??

Here is my code :

```
  moveFeatures(): void {
     if (this.selectInteraction) {
         let selectedFeatures = this.selectInteraction.getFeatures();
           if (selectedFeatures.getLength() != 0) {
               let translate = new Translate({
               features: selectedFeatures,
              // hitTolerance: 0.4,
      
             });
               this.map.addInteraction(translate);
         translate.on('translating', () => {
      this.toolbarComponent.getsnapping('Move');
    })
   
    translate.on('translateend', () => {
      selectedFeatures.clear();
    });
    
  }
   }
```

Comment: As with Modify in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/snap.html you need to add a Snap interaction after adding the Translate interaction https://codesandbox.io/s/snap-forked-hgfv9v?file=/main.js

Comment: thank you @ Mike but codesandbox.io/s/snap-forked-hgfv9v?file=/main.js  this doesn't work for polygon and line

Comment: It works within the pixel tolerance (default is 10), for large drawing you may need a larger tolerance https://codesandbox.io/s/snap-forked-kyzyqx?file=/main.js